# Updating a column in SQL based on two foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how you would go forward on updating a column by combining two foreign keys.

I have one table, FoodPackage, which looks like this:

```
create table FoodPackage(
PackageNumber int primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(45),
price int);
```

Another table, Product, which looks like this:

```
create table Product(
ProductID int primary key auto_increment,
Category varchar(45),
ProductName varchar(45),
Price int,
Allergy varchar(45));
```

And lastly, Orders, which looks like this:

```
create table Orders(
Ordernumber int primary key auto_increment,
PackageNumber int not null,
ProductID int not null,
UserID int not null,
Frequency int,
TotalPrice int,
OrderStatus varchar(45),
 FOREIGN KEY(PackageNumber)
    REFERENCES FoodPackage(PackageNumber),
 FOREIGN KEY(ProductID)
    REFERENCES Product(ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY(UserID)
    REFERENCES Users(UserID));
```

What I want to do is to update the totalprice column based on the values of FoodPackage.price and Product.Price combined. I have tried using an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE Orders, FoodPackage, Product SET Orders.TotalPrice= FoodPackage.Price + Product.Price;
```

However, this will only give me a constant value.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: You can only order one product and one package per order?

Comment: @Barmar Yes at the moment that is a problem. Do you know how I can add the possibility to allow the user to register multiple products and packages upon an order?

Comment: You should use a many-to-many junction table that relates orders to products, and another one that related orders to packages.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the excellent help. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a joining condition between the tables.

```
UPDATE Orders AS o
JOIN FoodPackage AS f ON o.PackageNumber = f.PackageNumber
JOIN Product AS p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
SET o.TotalPrice = f.Price + p.Price
```